# Serialize a Class Object using vars()?

Tags: python, class, serialization

beginner with Python here !

When serializing an instance in Python I tried using vars(), which returns returns the **dict** of said instance.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, doc_id, name):
        self.doc_id = doc_id
        self.name = name

user1 = Foo(3, "Eddy")

serialized = vars(user1)

print("user1", user1.__dict__)
print("serialized", serialized)
```

So far so  good.

```
user1 {'doc_id': 3, 'name': 'Eddy'}
serialized {'doc_id': 3, 'name': 'Eddy'}
```

I thought that `serialized` was now a dict with `{key: value}` copied from the instance `user`, but if I change a value like this:

```
serialized["name"] = Jo
```

It reverts the changes back to the instance.

```
print("serialized", serialized)
print("user1", user1.__dict__)
```

```
serialized {'doc_id': 3, 'name': 'Jo'}
user1 {'doc_id': 3, 'name': 'Jo'}
```

My two questions are:

- is `vars()` only use is to read attributes and not getting those attributes to modify them or am I missing something ?
- do I have to create my own method / function to create my dict if I want to tweak the value ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in Python, the `vars()` function returns the `__dict__` attribute of an object, which is a dictionary containing the object's attributes and their values. If the object has no **dict** attribute, an exception is raised. So that is all there is to it in this regard.

Then, when you have done `serialized["name"] = 'Jo'` (note the code in the question misses the quotes there) you have now change the value in the dict. So you should expect the dict to be modified.

So the result is:

```
serialized {'doc_id': 3, 'name': 'Jo'}
user1 {'doc_id': 3, 'name': 'Jo'}
```

And presumably this is desired (ie. what else are you trying to achieve) ?

**In answer to the second question**:
Yes, this is certainly an option and a more common way of changing the values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
to answer your question "what else i'm trying to achieve": i have a class (X) with an attribute (sub_element_list) which is a list of another class instances so when serializing i am trying to only get one attribute (id) of those instances. By serializing with vars() and tweaking it, iwas only left with the attributes (ids) in the sub_element_list.

Comment: so you are trying to share `sub_element_list` with the other instances ?  you can do this too by defining the `sub_element_list` before the `__init__` function so that it is in the class scope as opposed to the instance. . . if i have understood correctly. . . it might be worth asking a new reformatted question if that is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this somehow controversional question.
According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable **dict** attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their **dict** attributes (for example, classes use a types.MappingProxyType to prevent direct dictionary updates).

So since you've accessed dict variable of that object, you are allowed to have direct updates on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I thought assigning it to a variable would create a copy but it was more like a reference to the class.__dict__.
Still much to learn about variables!

Comment: Weirdness of python :)) You are welcome!